# IE edge: gaps between cells when using pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, title

i have a huge table (about 2000 rows with 60 cols) and on each cell is a title.
The title on empty cells is about 40 Bytes Long.
So the created webpage is huge. I wand to decrease the size of the webpage.
As I can's set a title in a class, I tried to solve it with pseudo elements.
See my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/derbestederbesten/gL30qujr/2/)

"info" is my tooltip/"title" Attribute

first table:

```
<td><span info>Content</span></td>
```

second table:

```
<td info>Content</td>
```

In the second table is a gap between the cells. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `[info]` to `display: inline-block;`. It's fine for spans but when you put `info` attribute on TD, this of course messes up table layout, because TD must have `display: table-cell`.

Move `inline-block` to `span[info]` only if you want it to be there:

```css
[info] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  padding: 4px;
}
span[info] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gL30qujr/3/

Comment: thank you very much. I work on Z-OS, so I'm not very familiar with web-development, but I guess I'm getting closer ....